# How many sequence of functions are there to converge pointwise to a given function on $E\subseteq \mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

yesterday night, I was studying sequence of functions in $\mathbb R$ and then this question came to mind.

When a sequence of real valued function is given, we can find out it's pointwise limit function on the same domain.

what about the converse?

Suppose a function $f$ on $E\subseteq \mathbb R$ is given. Can we find some sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ on $E$ such that $\lim f_n=f$ holds for all $x\in E$ ?

If yes, how many such is possible? meaning by, will this sequence of function be unique or there will be plenty of such? If plenty of such , then will it be countable or uncountable?

I tried to figure out but the only intuition that came to mind was "yes, there will be some sequence of functions converging pointwise to $f$". But after that, I am unable to establish it. Moreover, i have no idea for the other consequences

Comment: There are uncountably many such sequences. Consider $f_n = f + \epsilon/n$ where $\epsilon$ is any fixed real number.

Comment: @Bungo WOW!! thats cool. And in case, we are to search for series of functions to converge to f, then?

Comment: you get at least $f= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f2^{-n}$

Comment: And we can tweak the example given by @Quickbeam2k1 - for example, add $\epsilon$ to the first term and subtract $\epsilon$ from the second term, so the sum remains unchanged. In this way we obtain uncountably many distinct series that converge to $f$.

Comment: Awsome !! thanks to all of you. I am satisfied. Let me see if I can improve further on or not. Thank you once again @Bungo \Quickbeam2k1